# ProcessMitigation module in Powershell Windows Server 2016

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I’m using `Set- ProcessMitigation -Name <exe name> -Enable DEP,BottomUp, HighEntropy`  for enabling DEP and ASLR for specific applications. It worked fine in Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019.

In Windows Server 2016, ProcessMitigation module is not present. I tried manual install of the ProcessMitigation module v1.0.7. But the arguments for Enable is different. For ex: BottomUp is BottomUpASLR.

I couldn’t find any official docs regarding the same. Is there any new version which ships with windows 10 and later ? Where can I find it ?